# ActiveState Perl 5.6 and oAuth

Tags: perl, oauth

Is there an oAuth Modul for ActiveState perl 5.6 Windows (oAuth 1.0 should suffice), can't seem to find anything that says it is working with 5.6, all require at least 5.8.

Comment: Test::More is preparing to drop 5.6 support which will knock out most of CPAN.  Might make a good argument to upgrade now before you're forced to.

Answer (score 2):

See [OAuth::Lite](http://search.cpan.org/dist/OAuth-Lite/), by looking at "Perl/Platform Version Matrix" it passes it's tests on 5.6.2.

P.S. You will have more and more problems with perl 5.6, it is 11 years old and does not has Unicode support fully integrated into language.

Comment: It is well worth upgrading to a more modern Perl 5. Version 12 is stable and available from ActiveState — http://www.activestate.com/activeperl — and Strawberry — http://strawberryperl.com/

Comment: Thanks for the quick response :) Yes I know, and if it where up to me I'd be using python ;) or at least Perl 5.12